# JSF: How can I change input field values in a PhaseListener?

Tags: jsf, phaselistener

I'm trying to use a PhaseListener for the APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES phase for having **one central place** where I can **filter all input fields** and sanitize them without adding code to them individually.

In my first step, I've tried just to set one value to a field I left empty in the browser when submitting the form, but I got an Exception telling me that I can't set request parameters.

Below is my **experimental** PhaseListener. This version tests if I can change any input field content at all by setting one known field to a value.
Once I get that working, the final code shall iterate over all fields, get their content, sanitize it, and write it back to the request.

```
public class SanitizeRequestValuesPhaseListener implements PhaseListener {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public static final String SEARCH_FORM_INPUT_PRICE_TO = "searchForm:inputPriceTo";

  public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
    return PhaseId.APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES;
  }

  public void afterPhase(final PhaseEvent event) {
  }

  public void beforePhase(final PhaseEvent event) {
    final FacesContext facesContext = event.getFacesContext();
    final ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();

    System.out.println();
    final Map<String, String> requestParameters = externalContext.getRequestParameterMap();
    printMap(requestParameters, "Request Parameters");

    if (requestParameters.containsKey(SEARCH_FORM_INPUT_PRICE_TO)) {
      final String priceTo = requestParameters.get(SEARCH_FORM_INPUT_PRICE_TO);
      if (priceTo != null) {
        // just out of curiosity
        System.out.println(priceTo.getClass().getName());
      }
      try {
        requestParameters.put(SEARCH_FORM_INPUT_PRICE_TO, "120");
      } catch (final Throwable ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }

  private static void printMap(final Map<?, ?> reqAttrs, final String title) {
    final StringBuilder sb;
    sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (final Object key : reqAttrs.keySet()) {
      sb.append("* (");
      sb.append(key);
      sb.append("=");
      sb.append(reqAttrs.get(key));
      sb.append(")\n");
    }
    System.out.println(title);
    System.out.println(sb);
  }
}
```

Is there another way to change/override user input values?
Or shoud I use a completely different approach?
Remember: The important thing is to have once central place that handles all input fields across the whole web application.

Comment: Because I would have to add this <f:validate> to 937 input fields across the application and I want to spare me that work.

Comment: I think I have to explain a bit more. The value of 120 and this one field was just an experiment to see if I can make any changes at all. The real code would get the value of all fields, sanitize them, then write them back.

Comment: So the number of input fields is your metric for a badly designed application? I would call that a premature judgement. And although the project was already over 10 years old before it came to me and it needs some cleanup and modernization, I would not call it badly designed per se. This "sanitize all input fields" endeavour is part of the modernization. What's so bad about wanting **one central place** to catch all fields?

Comment: Nope, the fields have all an individual name/id. The constant in the example is there because my IDE offered to create it. As I wrote, the listener example was an experiment. The real code would just iterate over all fields, their names would not matter any more, and the constant would be gone. On the other hand, it is like it is, and I have a very limited budget (it's a communal site).

Comment: And BTW ... adding the same "sanitize input" contraint to all fields individually violates the "don't repeat yourself" paradigm. I would not call this an improvement.